# Kafka Connect JDBC sink connector not working

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to use Kafka Connect JDBC sink connector to insert data into Oracle but it is throwing an error . I have tried with all the possible configurations of the schema. Below is the examples .

Please suggest if I am missing anything below are my configurations files and errors.

### Case 1- First Configuration

```
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false .
```

so I am getting the

```
[2017-08-28 16:16:26,119] INFO Sink task WorkerSinkTask{id=oracle_sink-0} finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:233)

[2017-08-28 16:16:26,606] INFO Discovered coordinator dfw-appblx097-01.prod.walmart.com:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) for group connect-oracle_sink. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:597)

[2017-08-28 16:16:26,608] INFO Revoking previously assigned partitions [] for group connect-oracle_sink (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:419)

[2017-08-28 16:16:26,609] INFO (Re-)joining group connect-oracle_sink (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:432)

[2017-08-28 16:16:27,174] INFO Successfully joined group connect-oracle_sink with generation 26 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:399)

[2017-08-28 16:16:27,176] INFO Setting newly assigned partitions [DJ-7, DJ-6, DJ-5, DJ-4, DJ-3, DJ-2, DJ-1, DJ-0, DJ-9, DJ-8] for group connect-oracle_sink (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:262)

[2017-08-28 16:16:28,580] ERROR Task oracle_sink-0 threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:455)

org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: No fields found using key and value schemas for table: DJ

   at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.metadata.FieldsMetadata.extract(FieldsMetadata.java:190)

   at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.metadata.FieldsMetadata.extract(FieldsMetadata.java:58)

   at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:65)

   at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:62)

   at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:66)

   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:435)

   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:251)

   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:180)

   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:148)

   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:146)

   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:190)

   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

### 2nd Configuration -

```
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=true

internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=true
```

Log:

```
[2017-08-28 16:23:50,993] INFO Revoking previously assigned partitions [] for group connect-oracle_sink (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:419)

[2017-08-28 16:23:50,993] INFO (Re-)joining group connect-oracle_sink (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:432)

[2017-08-28 16:23:51,260] INFO (Re-)joining group connect-oracle_sink (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:432)

[2017-08-28 16:23:51,381] INFO Successfully joined group connect-oracle_sink with generation 29 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:399)

[2017-08-28 16:23:51,384] INFO Setting newly assigned partitions [DJ-7, DJ-6, DJ-5, DJ-4, DJ-3, DJ-2, DJ-1, DJ-0, DJ-9, DJ-8] for group connect-oracle_sink (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:262)

[2017-08-28 16:23:51,727] ERROR Task oracle_sink-0 threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:148)

org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload" fields and may not contain additional fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.

   at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:308)
```

Oracle connector.properties looks like

```
name=oracle_sink

connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector

tasks.max=1

topics=DJ

connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port:sid

connection.user=username

connection.password=password

#key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

#value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

auto.create=true

auto.evolve=true
```

Connect-Standalone.properties

**My JSON looks like -**

```
{"Item":"12","Sourcing Reason":"corr","Postal Code":"l45","OrderNum":"10023","Intended Node Distance":1125.8,"Chosen Node":"34556","Quantity":1,"Order Date":1503808765201,"Intended Node":"001","Chosen Node Distance":315.8,"Sourcing Logic":"reducesplits"}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_connector.html#data-mapping)

> The sink connector requires knowledge of schemas, so you should use a suitable converter e.g. the Avro converter that comes with the schema registry, or **the JSON converter with schemas enabled**.

So if your data is JSON you would have the following configuration:

```
[...]
"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
[...]
```

The error you see in the second instance is pertinent -- `JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload" fields` - the JSON you share does not meet this required format.

Here's a simple example of a valid JSON message with `schema` and `payload` :

```
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [{
            "type": "int32",
            "optional": true,
            "field": "c1"
        }, {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": true,
            "field": "c2"
        }, {
            "type": "int64",
            "optional": false,
            "name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp",
            "version": 1,
            "field": "create_ts"
        }, {
            "type": "int64",
            "optional": false,
            "name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp",
            "version": 1,
            "field": "update_ts"
        }],
        "optional": false,
        "name": "foobar"
    },
    "payload": {
        "c1": 10000,
        "c2": "bar",
        "create_ts": 1501834166000,
        "update_ts": 1501834166000
    }
}
```

What's your source for the data that you're trying to land to Oracle? If it's Kafka Connect inbound then you simply use the same `converter` configuration (Avro + Confluent Schema Registry) would be easier and more efficient. If it's a custom application, you'll need to get it to either (a) use the Confluent Avro serialiser or (b) write the JSON in the required format above, providing the schema of the payload inline with the message.

Comment: I have (15-20) kafka topics with each topic having different fields and different schema. I want to use the JDBC sink connector so that for each topic a table is created in oracle . Also in my case the JSON data has some nested fields as well which I guess is not handeled by sink converter. changing the schema of each topic  by including schema and payload field doesn't seems to be a good option .Any suggestion on how I can proceed with this use case.

Comment: "changing the schema of each topic by including schema and payload field doesn't seems to be a good option" -- You have to do that, or use Avro. Period. How else is the sink going to know the schema of the table that it is to load data for. What is the source of the data that you're loading?

Comment: there are some custom kafka producer applications which are reading from Oracle and writing into kafka topic and our requirement is to read those several kafka topics using kafka connect cluster and insert into Oracle data warehouse. a) Is it possible that I use schema registry and post schemas for all the for all the topics once and then trying running the JDBC sink connector to read the JSON data in kafka topic and insert into Oracle.

Comment: Why are you using custom Kafka producer applications to read from Oracle, and not Kafka Connect? Life is much simpler if you use Kafka Connect for all your integration :)

Comment: Because data is not coming only from one Oracle source there are multiple Oracle sources which are inserting into multiple topics .

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. You can use Kafka Connect to ingest from multiple tables, either with a single connector or multiple connectors.

Comment: Can I write a custom schema registry and then try to read the JSON data  in kafka topic and insert into oracle.

Comment: @Digvijay You would write a custom sink connector which parsers the json into jdbc records. You do not need need a registry

Comment: @RobinMoffatt i want to set `value.converter.schemas.enable` to `false` how can I put this mapping in connector ?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar Post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I've the same problem, after the read this post. I has been resolved with JDBC Sink MySQL
Below my Kafka Connect Configuration, as additional information:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8083/connectors/' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "jdbc-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "ttib-transactions",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.1:6603/tt-tran?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=false",
        "connection.user": "root",
        "connection.password": "*******",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://psrc-j55zm.us-central1.gcp.confluent.cloud",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "insert.mode": "insert",
        "batch.size":"0",
        "table.name.format": "${topic}",
        "pk.fields" :"id"
    }
}'
```