# How to solve Kafka Connect JSONConverter "Schema must contain 'type' field"

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Am trying to push a message to JdbcSink the message is as below

```
{
  "schema": {
    "type": "struct",
      "fields": [{
        "field": "ID",
        "type": {
          "type": "bytes",
          "scale": 0,
          "precision": 64,
          "connect.version": 1,
          "connect.parameters": {
            "scale": "0"
          },
          "connect.name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal",
          "logicalType": "decimal"
        }
      }, {
        "field": "STORE_DATE",
        "type": ["null", {
          "type": "long",
          "connect.version": 1,
          "connect.name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp",
          "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
        }],
        "default": null
      }, {
        "field": "DATA",
        "type": ["null", "string"],
        "default": null
      }],
        "name": "KAFKA_STREAM"
  },
    "payload": {
      "ID": 17,
        "STORE_DATE": null,
          "DATA": "THIS IS TEST DATA"
    }
}
```

but it keeps throwing error  `Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Schema must contain 'type' field`

this is the connector configuration am using currently

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "topics": "DEV_KAFKA_STREAM",
    "connection.url": "url",
    "connection.user": "user",
    "connection.password": "password",
    "insert.mode": "insert",
    "table.name.format": "KAFKA_STREAM",
    "pk.fields": "ID",
    "auto.create": "false",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true"
}
```

am not  sure how to debug this or how to find the root cause as the json does have `type` field

Comment: What's wrong with using Avro?

Comment: You can debug using KAFKA_DEBUG environment variable https://stackoverflow.com/a/58563270/2308683

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, `"long"` is not a valid Schema type.

You want `"int64"`

[JSON Schema source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.4.0/connect/json/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/json/JsonSchema.java#L39-L59)

And you may also want to remove the unions. There's a `optional` key to designate nullable fields

[Kafka Connect JDBC sink connector not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928768/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink-connector-not-working)

If you're creating that JSON in java, you should use SchemaBuilder and the Envelope class around two JSONNode objects to make sure you correctly build the payload

Comment: still same error ` Schema must contain 'type' field`

Comment: Do you get the same message when trying a schema from here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45940013/2308683 And I would remove the unions. You can set nullable fields using the optional key